# What folders can be copied with Mac OS X Migration Assistant

Tags: macos, migration-assistant

Is there a definitive list somewhere of all of the directories that *can* be copies by the OS X Migration Assistant?
For example, I am unsure if it will copy only ~/Library/ or /Library/ as well (User vs. System).
I have some application activation data that gets stored various places on the system (no lectures needed about where you should and shouldn't store such things... I didn't write it, I'm just updating it), but not all of it gets transfered when Migration Assistant is used.

So, if there is any complete list available, it would be really helpful, so I know where I should or shouldn't move the data to.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4413?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)? It includes "Network and Computer settings"...

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. But I need the actual directory paths that it uses.